# Vue - Form inside another form and submit event trigger

Tags: vue.js

I have a form inside another form and I want to prevent default action for both forms on submit event:

**Vue component:**

```
<template>
    <div v-show="isActive" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <slot :form="form"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Child:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/update-user">

    // form fields part 1

    <form method="GET" action="/delete-user">
        <button type="submit">
            <span>{{ $is_deleted ? 'Cancel Delete' : 'Delete Account' }}</span>
        </button>
    </form>

    // form fields part 2

    <button type="submit">
        <span>Update</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

When I submit `update-user` form then the component `onSubmit` method is hit and prevents default action. However, when I hit `delete-user` form then the `onSubmit` method is not hit and the page gets reloaded.

If I get the second form outside of the first one, then it works.

How I can trigger `onSubmit` method for the second form?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but check out this article. [Proper Form Handling in VueJS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-form-handling).

Comment: You can also look into vee-validate, where you can build nested forms. Very good if your forms become more advanced and advanced validations, like custom validators. If this is your only form and no validations, then perhaps vee-validate is not needed. But just for future if you do need some better tool to build forms :) There is also vuelidate, but I have no experience of that.

Answer (score 2):

No, This looks like nested form and it violates the spec as outlined in [Prohibitions](http://%20https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions).

Form must not contain another form. I think you should design your app differently. May be two different forms. Or just use plain ajax request as its a vue app anyway?

Comment: Thank you, I guess I will have to get the nested form outside and just use some onclick button event to submit when clicked.